# Creating indirect indexes with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mlab

Is it possible to create an `index` that searches on fields of other documents referenced by id?

For example, if I want to search of articles by names of authors associated with them, and the names themselves are not stored in the Articles collection but the Authors collection.

Any instructions on how to do it in `Mlab` would be great.

Comment: So, why don't you search authors then?

Comment: This is for doing a search on a website, and I want to return a list of Articles by Authors matched by name.

Comment: Yes, find authors by name, _then_ find articles by author ids.